Empty Date Parameter Returning Incorrect JSON Object in Express.js
I'm currently working on the FreeCodeCamp Timestamp Microservice project and I've encountered an issue with the implementation. While most of the requirements pass successfully, I'm having trouble with the test case for handling an empty date parameter. Here are the specifics:
Passed Tests:

A request to /api/:date? with a valid date returns a JSON object with unix and utc keys.
A request to /api/1451001600000 returns the correct timestamp.
The project can handle dates parsed by new Date(date_string).
Invalid date strings return { error: "Invalid Date" }.

Failed Tests:

An empty date parameter should return the current time in a JSON object with a unix key.
An empty date parameter should return the current time in a JSON object with a utc key.
Here’s the code I’m using:

// index.js
// where your node app starts

// init project
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

// enable CORS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)
// so that your API is remotely testable by FCC 
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({ optionsSuccessStatus: 200 }));  // some legacy browsers choke on 204

// http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html
app.use(express.static('public'));

// http://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');
});

const isInvalidDate = (date) => date.toUTCString() === "Invalid Date"

// your first API endpoint... 
app.get("/api/:date", function (req, res) {
  let date = new Date(req.params.date)

  if (isInvalidDate(date)) {
    date = new Date(+req.params.date)
  }

  if (isInvalidDate(date)) {
    res.json({ error: "Invalid Date" })
    return;
  }

  res.json({
    unix: date.getTime(),
    utc: date.toUTCString()
  });
});

app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    unix: new Date().getTime(),
    utc: new Date().toUTCString()
  })
})



// listen for requests :)
var listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT, function () {
  console.log('Your app is listening on port ' + listener.address().port);
});


I expected that when making a request to /api/ or /api, the server would return the current time in both Unix and UTC formats as a JSON object.

Doesn't really make sense, because requests to /api/ (where the date parameter is empty) will be handled by your second handler (for /api), which does exactly what the requirements demand. Unless you're using strict routing and forgot to mention that?

Thank you! It turns out my system clock was incorrect, which was causing the issue. Thanks anyway!

First, you need to place the route for the empty date parameter (/api) before the route with the date parameter (/api/:date), Second for the date issues, you need to add proper handling for an empty date parameter.
// index.js
// where your node app starts

// init project
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

// enable CORS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)
// so that your API is remotely testable by FCC 
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({ optionsSuccessStatus: 200 }));  // some legacy browsers choke on 204

// http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html
app.use(express.static('public'));

// http://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');
});

const isInvalidDate = (date) => date.toUTCString() === "Invalid Date"

// your first API endpoint... 
app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
  const currentDate = new Date();
  res.json({
    unix: currentDate.getTime(),
    utc: currentDate.toUTCString()
  });
});

app.get("/api/:date", function (req, res) {
  let date = req.params.date;

  // Handle an empty date parameter
  if (!date) {
    date = new Date();
  } else {
    date = new Date(isNaN(date) ? date : parseInt(date));
  }

  if (isInvalidDate(date)) {
    res.json({ error: "Invalid Date" });
    return;
  }

  res.json({
    unix: date.getTime(),
    utc: date.toUTCString()
  });
});

// listen for requests :)
var listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT, function () {
  console.log('Your app is listening on port ' + listener.address().port);
});



Thank you! It turns out my system clock was incorrect, which was causing the issue. Thanks anyway!
